# Updating child component from inside the function body of a parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-devtools

I have a parent component which contains some `Filters` as a child which looks like:

```
type TProps = {
  filters: Array<IFilter | IDateFilter>;
  updateFilter: (field: string, selectedElements: Array<string>) => void;
  resetFilter: (field: string) => void;
  resetFilters: () => void;
};

const Filters: React.FC<TProps> = (props: TProps) => (
  <div className={styles.wrapper}>
    <FilterBar {...props} />
  </div>
);
```

`Filters` child in the parent component:

```
<Filters
   filters={filters}
   updateFilter={updateFilter}
   resetFilters={resetFilters}
   resetFilter={resetFilter}
/>
```

`filters` state in the parent component: `const [filters, setFilters] = useState<Array<IFilter | IDateFilter>>([]);`

`updateFilter` method expects a couple of arguments and is written in the parent like below:

```
const updateFilter = (field: string, selectedElements: Array<string>) => {
    setFilters(filters => {
      const updatedFilters = filters.map(filter => {
        if (filter.field === field) {
          return { ...filter, selectedElements: [...selectedElements] };
        }
        return filter;
      });
      return updatedFilters;
    });
  };
```

`resetFilter` & `resetFilters` have a similar structure to this.
once they are triggered, an effect takes place as in the parent `filters` change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchStuff();
  }, [filters]);
```

Although they seem to be working, I have this on my console `Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.`
As advised here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18147, I have tried the approach with `useEffect` as well as `useCallback` but they didn't seem to work as `updateFilter` expects some arguments for it to be called with.

Comment: Can you provide more code, cant find the problem with it

Comment: Hey Ozko, you can edit the question itself and put the code you pasted in the comment in the question. Just click the edit button on the question.

Comment: just did that, cheers.